# delete messages based on user property's using wlst

Tags: jms, wlst

Hi I am able to delete JMS message in the queue using JMS Message ID but not able to delete the message based user property, can you help me here

```
connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxxx')
servers = domainRuntimeService.getServerRuntimes();
for server in servers:
        jmsRuntime = server.getJMSRuntime();
        jmsServers = jmsRuntime.getJMSServers();
        for jmsServer in jmsServers:
             destinations = jmsServer.getDestinations();
             for destination in destinations:
                 desname=destination.getName()
                 MessagesCurrentCount=destination.getMessagesCurrentCount()
                 if MessagesCurrentCount == 0:
                         if desname == "QUEUE_RESPONSE":
#                            print 'Message Current Count  '+ str(MessagesCurrentCount) +' '
#                                        destination.deleteMessages("JMSMessageID IN('ID:<786419.1533793370330.0>')")
                                         selector = "ORDER_PRIMARY_KEY like 'jack%'";
                                          timeout = 0;
                                          destination.getMessages(selector,timeout);
                                          destination.deleteMessages("selector")
```

Comment: Hi Jack, please format your code so as to prevent hyphema in potential answerers.

Comment: Hi just wanted to know why my getmessages function is not able extract the message based on user propertys !!Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fishy:

```
destination.deleteMessages("selector")
```

try:

```
destination.deleteMessages(selector)
```

:-)